# Run SQL Server Management Studio locally to connect to a remote server on AWS (RDS instance)

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, sql-server-2008-r2, amazon-rds

I have a RDS instance with SQL Server 2008 R2 (SQL Server EE 10.50.6529.0.v1). For security reason, we don't allow direct connection to this DB from our on-prem network. This RDS allows connection ONLY if coming from our app server; the security group has been set up accordingly.

The problem is sometimes we need to connect to SQL Server RDS instance

[image: connection diagram]

For this purpose, I was thinking can we use SQL Server Management Studio which is installed on my local machine to connect to this remote server? Note: we have connectivity to our app server from on premise. We can RDP to the app server using jumpbox/ bastion.

My idea is, run SQL Server Management Studio locally (on premise) and connect to app server and from there go to RDS. on-prem-->app (RDP:3389)--> RDS (ms sql:1433). My local path to SSMS is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\SSMS.exe
```

Comment: do you have a Linux bastion host or server which can connect to rds instance? how about configuring `ssh tunnel` through that to RDS?

Comment: unfortunately, our app server is win 12 r2

Answer (score 1):

SSH tunnel is the solution,
use this cmd
ssh -N -L 3333:rds-url:3306 user@appserver-ip -i ~/.ssh/appserver.pem
then connect to rds in local using port 3333

Comment: so, if the end user has a windows machine (windows 7/10), how can they use SSH tunnel, like using putty? Would you pls elaborate?